# example of graph whose radius equals its diameter but is not self-centered?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an example of a graph whose radius equals its diameter but which is not self-centered?  I.e, a graph for which some vertex is not a central vertex?

Answer (score 2):

The diameter of a graph is the maximum eccentricity of its vertices, while the radius of a graph is the minimum eccentricity. Thus if the radius and diameter are equal, each vertex has the same eccentricity. Hence each vertex is a central vertex.

So the answer is: no.

Comment: That makes sense.  So is it correct to say that a graph is self centred if and only if its radius equals its diameter?  Or is there some degenerate case I'm not considering?

Comment: Yes, that is right.